# Displaying tweets in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm a Rails noob and I'm following a blog post I found [here...](http://www.arctickiwi.com/blog/download-you-twitter-feed-using-ruby-on-rails-with-oauth)

I have everything working up until the end. Then things get nebulous.

So if I have this in my helper...

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def display_content_with_links(tweet)
    tweet.content.gsub(/(http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/\.\+\-_:?&=]+)/) {|a| "<a href=\"#{a}\">#{a}</a>"}
  end
end
```

Shouldn't I be able to have my tweets display in my view with this...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you seeing on your page? Have you run the rake task to populate the tweets yet? It may not be an issue with the code above.

Comment: Following Toby's answer (which from what I can tell should work) I'm now getting this error.."no such file to load -- grackle" I'm on Ruby 1.9.2p290 and grackel 0.1.10 is listed as installed when I run "gem list" from terminal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need a controller and view to have this display.  Something simple like:

```
# app/controller/tweets_controller.rb
TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @tweets = Tweet.get_latest
  end
end
```

and in the view:

```
# app/views/tweets/index.html.haml
%ul
  - @tweets.each do |tweet|
    %li
      = display_content_with_links tweet
```

or if you use erb

```
# app/views/tweets/index.html.erb
<ul>
  <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <li>
       <%= display_content_with_links tweet %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This is a pretty basic example that might not even come close to what you want, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: The only thing I would change is the example sets it up as `Tweet.get_latest` instead of `Tweet.all`.  Other than that, nice answer

Comment: LoadError in TweetsController#index

no such file to load -- grackle
Rails.root: /Users/gideon/Desktop/ca_railswork/week10/birdie

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/tweet.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   grackle

Comment: Did you do the `gem install grackle` from the link you provided?  I have never used the grackle gem, so not sure what could be up with that.  You may want to check out https://github.com/hayesdavis/grackle/ to see what it does.  I skimmed over the readme and didn't see anything that would help with that error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should add

```
@tweet = Tweet.all
```

To the controller#action you have setup already, then iterate over them in your view:

```
<ul>
  <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <li><%= display_content_with_links tweet %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```